# way of comparision of math.h sin() float result with optimised fixed point result

Tags: floating-point, fixed-point

I have optimized sin functions for my client hardware. But I want to compare standard floating point sin function with optimized fixed point sin function .

I am doing my work in 4 stages :

```
1) Input generation (floating point to fixed point conversation):Input.y
2) Reference *.cpp code execution in fixed point(output is fixed point):Ref.y
3) Optimization code execution on hardware (output is fixed point):Optimized.y
4) Comparison of ref output with optimized (stage3) output in fixed point:(Ref.y == Optimized.y) ?
```

At the end of these stages, I am getting True bit exactness in fixed point .
But I also need to verify my fixed point output with floating point result generated by standard mathlib (math.h) header sin function.

I am able to generate floating point results from `sin` function from `math.h` file. But,Can any one suggest me which is the best way to compare floating point result with fixed point :

```
1) convert once again floating point result of standard sin function result to fixed point and compare with fixed point Ref.y 
2) convert fixed point Ref.y to floating point point and compare the result of float with float .
```

Please also suggest me how I can compare float with float. I mean this is not the correct way I can compare (3.4 == 3.4) because of precision issue .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no special requirements applicable to your use case, the "standard" approach is to convert the fixed-point result to `double` (this is an error-free transformation for most common fixed-point formats), and compute the absolute error of that versus the standard math library's `sin(double)` result:

`absolute_error = fabs (result - reference)`

If feasible for the given fixed-point format an exhaustive test is advisable. On a modern machine, 2<sup>32</sup> function evaluations are typically easily computed within minutes. Your test would want to record the *maximum* absolute error observed, as well as compute the root mean square ([RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square)) error across all results.

For a periodic function like `sin`, you may observe that the phase error grows with the magnitude of the arguments due to an insufficiently precise approximation to π used in the argument reduction. Your use case will determine what is acceptable in this regard.

Below is a worked example, using a particular fixed-point implementation of `log2` as the function under test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

#define FRAC_BITS_OUT (16)
#define INT_BITS_OUT  (15)
#define FRAC_BITS_IN  (31)
#define INT_BITS_IN   ( 0)

#define USE_TABLE     (1)

/* count leading zeros: intrinsic or machine instruction on many architectures */
int32_t clz (uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t n, y;

    n = 31 + (!x);
    if ((y = (x & 0xffff0000U))) { n -= 16;  x = y; }
    if ((y = (x & 0xff00ff00U))) { n -=  8;  x = y; }
    if ((y = (x & 0xf0f0f0f0U))) { n -=  4;  x = y; }
    if ((y = (x & 0xccccccccU))) { n -=  2;  x = y; }
    if ((    (x & 0xaaaaaaaaU))) { n -=  1;         }
    return n;
}

#if USE_TABLE

#define LOG2_TBL_SIZE (6)
#define TBL_SIZE      ((1 << LOG2_TBL_SIZE) + 2)

/* for i = [0,65]: log2(1 + i/64) * (1 << 31) */
const uint32_t log2Tab [TBL_SIZE] =
{
    0x00000000, 0x02dcf2d1, 0x05aeb4dd, 0x08759c50, 
    0x0b31fb7d, 0x0de42120, 0x108c588d, 0x132ae9e2, 
    0x15c01a3a, 0x184c2bd0, 0x1acf5e2e, 0x1d49ee4c, 
    0x1fbc16b9, 0x22260fb6, 0x24880f56, 0x26e2499d, 
    0x2934f098, 0x2b803474, 0x2dc4439b, 0x30014ac6, 
    0x32377512, 0x3466ec15, 0x368fd7ee, 0x38b25f5a, 
    0x3acea7c0, 0x3ce4d544, 0x3ef50ad2, 0x40ff6a2e, 
    0x43041403, 0x450327eb, 0x46fcc47a, 0x48f10751, 
    0x4ae00d1d, 0x4cc9f1ab, 0x4eaecfeb, 0x508ec1fa, 
    0x5269e12f, 0x5440461c, 0x5612089a, 0x57df3fd0, 
    0x59a80239, 0x5b6c65aa, 0x5d2c7f59, 0x5ee863e5, 
    0x60a02757, 0x6253dd2c, 0x64039858, 0x65af6b4b, 
    0x675767f5, 0x68fb9fce, 0x6a9c23d6, 0x6c39049b, 
    0x6dd2523d, 0x6f681c73, 0x70fa728c, 0x72896373, 
    0x7414fdb5, 0x759d4f81, 0x772266ad, 0x78a450b8, 
    0x7a231ace, 0x7b9ed1c7, 0x7d17822f, 0x7e8d3846, 
    0x80000000, 0x816fe50b
};

#define RND_SHIFT     (31 - FRAC_BITS_OUT)
#define RND_CONST     ((1 << RND_SHIFT) / 2)
#define RND_ADJUST    (0x10d) /* established heuristically */

/* 
   compute log2(x) in s15.16 format, where x is in s0.31 format
   maximum absolute error 8.18251e-6 @ 0x20352845 (0.251622232)
*/   
int32_t fixed_log2 (int32_t x)
{
    int32_t f1, f2, dx, a, b, approx, lz, i, idx;
    uint32_t t;

    /* x = 2**i * (1 + f), 0 <= f < 1. Find i */
    lz = clz (x);
    i = INT_BITS_IN - lz;
    /* normalize f */
    t = (uint32_t)x << (lz + 1);
    /* index table of log2 values using LOG2_TBL_SIZE msbs of fraction */
    idx = t >> (32 - LOG2_TBL_SIZE);
    /* difference between argument and smallest sampling point */
    dx = t - (idx << (32 - LOG2_TBL_SIZE));
    /* fit parabola through closest three sampling points; find coeffs a, b */
    f1 = (log2Tab[idx+1] - log2Tab[idx]);
    f2 = (log2Tab[idx+2] - log2Tab[idx]);
    a = f2 - (f1 << 1);
    b = (f1 << 1) - a;
    /* find function value for argument by computing ((a*dx+b)*dx) */
    approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)a)*dx) >> (32 - LOG2_TBL_SIZE)) + b;
    approx = (int32_t)((((int64_t)approx)*dx) >> (32 - LOG2_TBL_SIZE + 1));
    approx = log2Tab[idx] + approx;
    /* round fractional part of result */
    approx = (((uint32_t)approx) + RND_CONST + RND_ADJUST) >> RND_SHIFT;
    /* combine integer and fractional parts of result */
    return (i << FRAC_BITS_OUT) + approx;
}

#else // USE_TABLE

/* on 32-bit architectures, there is often an instruction/intrinsic for this */
int32_t mulhi (int32_t a, int32_t b)
{
    return (int32_t)(((int64_t)a * (int64_t)b) >> 32);
}

#define RND_SHIFT  (25 - FRAC_BITS_OUT)
#define RND_CONST  ((1 << RND_SHIFT) / 2)
#define RND_ADJUST (-2) /* established heuristically */

/* 
    compute log2(x) in s15.16 format, where x is in s0.31 format
    maximum absolute error 1.11288e-5 @ 0x5a82689f (0.707104757)
*/   
int32_t fixed_log2 (int32_t x)
{
    int32_t lz, i, f, p, approx;
    uint32_t t;
    /* x = 2**i * (1 + f), 0 <= f < 1. Find i */
    lz = clz (x);
    i = INT_BITS_IN - lz;
    /* force (1+f) into range [sqrt(0.5), sqrt(2)] */
    t = (uint32_t)x << lz;    
    if (t > (uint32_t)(1.414213562 * (1U << 31))) {
        i++;
        t = t >> 1;
    }
    /* compute log2(1+f) for f in [-0.2929, 0.4142] */
    f = t - (1U << 31);
    p =              + (int32_t)(-0.206191055 * (1U << 31) -  1);
    p = mulhi (p, f) + (int32_t)( 0.318199910 * (1U << 30) - 18);
    p = mulhi (p, f) + (int32_t)(-0.366491705 * (1U << 29) + 22);
    p = mulhi (p, f) + (int32_t)( 0.479811855 * (1U << 28) -  2);
    p = mulhi (p, f) + (int32_t)(-0.721206390 * (1U << 27) + 37);
    p = mulhi (p, f) + (int32_t)( 0.442701618 * (1U << 26) + 35);
    p = mulhi (p, f) + (f >> (31 - 25));
    /* round fractional part of the result */
    approx = (p + RND_CONST + RND_ADJUST) >> RND_SHIFT;
    /* combine integer and fractional parts of result */
    return (i << FRAC_BITS_OUT) + approx;
}

#endif // USE_TABLE

/* convert from s15.16 fixed point to double-precision floating point */
double fixed_to_float_s15_16 (int32_t a)
{
    return a / 65536.0;
}

/* convert from s0.31 fixed point to double-precision floating point */
double fixed_to_float_s0_31 (int32_t a)
{
    return a / (65536.0 * 32768.0);
}

int main (void)
{
    double a, res, ref, err, rmserr, sumerrsq = 0.0, maxerr = 0.0;
    int32_t x, start, end, nbrtests = 0;

    start = 0x00000001;
    end =   0x7fffffff;
    printf ("testing fixed_log2 with inputs in [%17.10e, %17.10e)\n",  
            fixed_to_float_s0_31 (start), fixed_to_float_s0_31 (end));
    printf ("using %s to compute log2\n", USE_TABLE ? "table" : "polynomial");

    for (x = start; x < end; x++) {
        a = fixed_to_float_s0_31 (x);
        ref = log2 (a);
        res = fixed_to_float_s15_16 (fixed_log2 (x));
        err = fabs (res - ref);
        sumerrsq += err * err;
        nbrtests++;
        if (err > maxerr) {
            maxerr = err;
        }
    }

    rmserr = sqrt (sumerrsq / nbrtests);
    printf ("max. error = %g  RMS error = %g\n", maxerr, rmserr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above program executes in a few minutes on my elderly PC, and depending on the algorithm choice, will produce output like this:

```
testing fixed_log2 with inputs in [4.6566128731e-010, 9.9999999953e-001)
using polynomial to compute log2
max. error = 1.11288e-005  RMS error = 4.65419e-006

testing fixed_log2 with inputs in [4.6566128731e-010, 9.9999999953e-001)
using table to compute log2
max. error = 8.18251e-006  RMS error = 4.40727e-006
```

Comment: Thanks @njuffa for this reply .It really helped me .Just one question.How to set the acceptable range if I do not have the predefined range .and also I want to set this acceptable rage depends upon the fixed point format .for example if the format is **f2s30**  or **f10s22** ..here 2 and 10 can represent the integer part of the input in fixed point and 30 and 22 represent the fractional part .

Comment: The function domain you need to test will depend on your use case. As default I would suggest exhaustive test of the available encodings (so `0x00000000` through `0xFFFFFFFF` for a 32-bit format). For the logarithm that I showed as an example we would want to exclude `0x00000000` and `0x80000000` - `0xFFFFFFFF` for obvious reasons: The result at 0 is -infinity which isn't representable in a fixed-point format, and for negative inputs the function isn't defined (would return NaN in floating-point, but there is no NaN in fixed point). Neither of those issues exists in the case of `sin()`.